# Syntax Error, Insert } to Complete Block

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Programming {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

        int l=0;
        StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

        public static boolean matchCharAt(StringBuilder password, int l){
            l = password.length();
            if (l < 0 || l > 100){
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < password.length();i++){
                if (!Character.isLetter(password.charAt(l)))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
```

It says I have an error on the line with `{         for (l=0; l < 100; l++);          }`, but i'm not sure if thats where the Curly brace error is.  It might not be a curly brace error, i'm unsure, but I was hoping I could get some help to not have this error.

Comment: Are you sure you copy & pasted your code properly? You're declaring a method within another method.

Comment: There are so many problems with this code. To start: you cannot declare a method in another method.

Answer (score 8):

You never close the `main()` method block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    int l=0;
    StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

    {
        for (l = 0; l < 100; l++);
    }
}  //HERE!
```

Besides this loop:

```
for (l = 0; l < 100; l++);
```

is not doing anything except changing the value of `l` to `100`. Also the loop is surrounded with a block that has no practical sense. I can only guess this is what you wanted:

```
for (l = 0; l < 100; l++) {
    matchCharAt(password, l);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is corollary to your main problem, but you are also changing an argument in this method

```
public static boolean matchCharAt(StringBuilder password, int l){
        l = password.length();
        if (l < 0 || l > 100){
            return false;
        }
```

If you're passing in `l`, then you're going to be changing its value with `l = password.length()`.

Comment: +1, good one! An argument to prefer `final` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want.  This should at least compile:

```
public class SomeClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

      int l=0;
      StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

      for (l = 0; l < 100; l++) {
        ; // Does nothing...
      }
  } // end of "main()"

  public static boolean matchCharAt(StringBuilder password, int l){
    l = password.length();
    if (l < 0 || l > 100){
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < password.length();i++){
        if (!Character.isLetter(password.charAt(l)))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
  } // end of "matchCharAt()"

 } // end of class
```